# Batch buck insert into Sybase IQ

Tags: sqoop, sap-iq

Sybase IQ is Columnar database,

I am thinking to bulk insert  100M records from Hive into Sybase IQ table with Sqoop(20 mappers).

It is said that Columnar database doesn't provide a good performance for bulk insert, so I would ask whether it is suitable to insert 100M records with Sqoop.

Comment: Sybase IQ is extremely good for (bulk) INSERT and SELECT, but not so good for UPDATE, so your assumption is wrong. It is one of the reason why Sybase is a Top RDBMS in BI/datawarehousing world, and is NOT for operational databases

Comment: Thanks @thomas-g for the helpful answer!